# How influential was Dune in the creation of Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, dune, inspiration

There are claims that Dune has been influential in, and an inspiration for the writing and creation of Star Wars.

In what ways is that evidenced? Please give examples.

Comment: This seems really broad. Any answer would speak about the dozens of influences on Star Wars that Lucas has mentioned over the years; Hidden Fortress, the monomyth, Flash Gordon, etc etc. We know from interviews that Lucas has read Dune and we know that Herbert felt that they were a bit too close for comfort.

Comment: http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/cover_story/2015/12/star_wars_is_a_pastiche_how_george_lucas_combined_flash_gordon_westerns.html

Comment: I see what you mean by too broad. What if I change it to ask for specific examples of influence in Star Wars ONLY and remove the mention of how it is said that Dune was influential in other media?

Comment: The question of whether Herbert thought they were related is answerable (spoiler, yes he did).

Comment: The question of whether Lucas has acknowleged that he lifted ideas from Dune is answerable (spoiler, no he hasn't).

Comment: I've seen lots of people [comparing Dune with Star Wars](https://www.reddit.com/r/starwarsspeculation/comments/6gp1s6/the_original_star_wars_was_created_when_george/) but some of the links seem *really* tenuous. For examples; "**Empire ruled by shadowy background character"** (wut?), **Protagonist has a sister-ally of the same parentage** (she wasn't even supposed to be his sister when the original movie was written), **Protagonist prefers saber** (no he doesn't. Luke doesn't use his lightsaber even once).

Comment: @Valorum - Is that last bit a joke?

Comment: I want to read the whole Dune series of books. It is likely that I will end up seeing all the influence and be a little disenchanted with the lack of 'transparency' on the part of the 'borrowers', so to speak...lol

Comment: @Adamant - Excluding the training sequence, in A New Hope Luke uses his lightsaber precisely zero times.

Comment: @Valorum *Any answer would speak about the dozens of influences on Star Wars that Lucas has mentioned over the years; Hidden Fortress, the monomyth, Flash Gordon, etc etc.* Well, the question is focused on Dune an IMHO so should the answer; it is the answer that will go describing ALL the influences of Star Wars that would be too broad (and not even entirely on topic), not the question itself. This question is legit for me.

Comment: I can see where Frank Herbert might think there were some similarities between Star Wars and Dune. Much of the early action takes place on a desert planet. Han Solo And many other in Mos Eisley are Spice smugglers just as there are Spice smugglers on Arrakis although canon now says Spice does not come frommTatooine it's not clear in Star Wars. From a certain point of view the Sandpeople of Tatooine with their flowing robes and filter masks etc could be seen as being inspired by the Fremen.

Comment: Just to clarify: are we talking the movies or the books? Because the way I heard it David Lynch was originally slated to direct Empire but when that fell through he used a lot of the ideas he was going to use for it and put them into Dune instead. The clearest example I can think of is the voice-weapon from Dune was originally meant to be a Jedi kind of gun (have to focus Force and use the voice, as opposed to a simple blaster. A more elegant gun for a more elegant age I suppose.)

Comment: @RogueJedi Sorry, but I think your edit changes the scope of the question too much. Asking for similarities between the two works is very different from asking for which similarities Lucas has *admitted* (which, if he did steal a lot of ideas from Dune, are likely to be only the smaller ones). The former is seeking a detailed comparison of themes and tropes; the latter could be answered by anyone with a Google search.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - You appear to have rolled the question back to the version which was previously closed. RogueJedi's edit was an attempt to fix the question by making it less of a "*grab bag of stuff that people on the internet reckon is similar*" question

Comment: @Valorum I've brought the issue to [Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11453/51226)

Answer (score 4):

Desert planet, good v. evil, corrupt and established authority v. young whippersnapper;  these are all prototype sci-fi concepts.  Herbert's greatest contribution was to bring awareness of ecological themes to science fiction and to describe an intricate and alternative lifestyle (and an alternative and nascent religion) that you'd be hard pressed to find a hint of in Star Wars. **Dune** (the book, anyway) is a masterpiece, although the many sequels significantly diluted that original potency.  Star Wars at least has that much in common.

Comment: Plus one just for the last couple of sentences. Pretty sure I recall GL denying any connections and claimed not to know about Dune prior to Star Wars.

Comment: I might be wrong. Seems to be a good analysis [here](http://www.moongadget.com/origins/dune.html).

Comment: This just seems to be a bunch of disjointed guesswork without any evidence of connection.

Comment: You trail off with, "...that you'd be hard pressed to find a hint of in Star Wars. " So are you saying Star Wars has none of what you described as what Dune is all about?

Comment: This is all correct but comprises a very poor answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: Darren: thank you for the link! It would seem that the article it points to is spot on. Write that up as an answer and I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

***There is no direct evidence***.

The following is a list of similarities according to an article I found a few weeks ago when I had the exact same question. Short of direct evidence or a quote from Lucas, to what extent these similarities actually did serve as an inspiration or how influential they were for Star Wars, will most likely be relegated to opinion. Some of them might be a stretch as they could simply represent story-telling archetypes rather than a direct inspiration (such as the Trade Monopoly or the use of Electronic-Binoculars), or just plain genre staples (such as the anti-grav devices). I found several statements claiming Lucas himself has acknowledged that Dune served as an inspiration but I have not been able to find direct evidence for this. It seems that Lucas took his inspiration from several SciFi stories rather than just Dune. I think it would be more correct to say that Star Wars was, in part, influenced by some the elements in Dune rather than to say that Dune was the direct inspiration for Star Wars. Note how the paragraph I quoted says "lesser borrowings", the author himself seems to be aware that some of the similarities are tenuous, while others seem to be a strong indicator that a few things were indeed directly borrowed (Princess Leia, Princess Alia; Moisture Farmers, Dew Collectors; Jedi Bendu; Prana Bindu; Metaphysical abilities which seem more at home in a Fantasy setting rather than SciFi)

"In early drafts of the Star Wars script the influence was much more obvious - the story was full of feudalistic Houses and dictums, and the treasure the Princess was guarding wasn't the Death Star plans, but a shipment of "aura spice." The final version of Star Wars is related to Dune mostly in spirit: a science fiction heroic fantasy treated seriously. Of all the ideas George Lucas inherited from Frank Herbert, the subtle lesson was how to use science fiction to create myth. His lesser borrowings might include:"

### **Star Wars**----------------------------------------------**Dune**

Princess Leia - Princess Alia

Villain turns out to be hero's father - Villain turns out to be
   Villain's grandfather

Sandcrawler: Vehicle piloted by Jawas - Sandcrawler: Vehicle piloted
   by Arrakins

Moisture Farmers (like Uncle Owen) - Dew Collectors (Fremen)

Spice Mines of Kessel - Spice is the key commodity in the Dune
   Universe

Metaphysical abilities which are exclusive to a select group of
   people: Jedi Mind Trick - The Voice (Bene Gesserit)

Metaphysical Training routines: Jedi Bendu (a Jedi training
   technique) - Prana Bindu (a Bene Gesserit training technique

Vision of Obi-Wan appears to Luke on Hoth while he is dying - Vision
   of Pardot Kynes appears to Liet-Kynes while he is dying

The Trade Federation has a monopoly on shipping in Space - The
   Spacing guild has a monopoly on shipping and Transportation in Space

Luke practices fighting against an automated training dummy (a floating orb shooting painful lasers)-
   Alia and Paul practice fighting against a humanoid automated training dummy

Repulsors, small devices used to counteract gravity (used in the
   Landspeeder, speeder bikes and Jabba's barge) - Suspensors small devices used to counteract gravity (used by Baron Harkonnen and Glowglobes)

sources: http://www.moongadget.com/origins/dune.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sources_and_analogues

Comment: A lot of these seem *really tenuous.* The Trade Federation most certainly don't have a monopoly on space travel, for example. Luke doesn't use a dummy, he uses a floating ball drone thing. And most of the references you're referring to are blink-and-you'll-miss-it references, possibly to Dune but certainly not a major part of the plot.

Comment: It seems tenuous to say that it's inspired by Dune because it has a desert planet. Lots of films of that era filmed in the desert because it was near California and had no need for filming permits.

Comment: Correct. Even in my original answer I never said that the similarities are part of any major Dune plot, in fact I *even pointed out* that the similarities are lesser. Also, even in my original answer I said nowhere that "Star Wars was directly inspired by Dune because it has a Desert Planet". Nothing you say contradicts anything I said in any way.

Comment: **<argumentative comments deleted>** Please keep comments constructive and helpful.

Comment: Intersting analysis, but a number of these items may not be applicable -- they seem based on the MOVIE Dune, not the book.  The movie wasn't around when Star Wars came out.  The training dummy, for example, was only a barrel with things shooting out in the film; in the books, it was basically a mannequin. The Duke's Ornithopter was in danger of not being able to take off, but wasn't almost eaten by the worm in the book; I don't remember if the movie showed that. Likewise, electrobinoculars are never mentioned; they use Oil Binoculars with a static charge and force field to focus, in the book.

Comment: @K-H-W - David Lynch was offered Star Wars: ROTJ to direct but turned it down after having watched the previous two films and meeting with George Lucas. Shortly afterwards he directed Dune. There seems to be pretty compelling evidence that his shooting style was influenced by Star Wars.

Comment: @Valorum - Certainly.  But the question is the other way around -- Not did Star Wars influence **the first film version** of Dune, but "How influential was Dune **(not a movie at the time when Star Wars was created)** in the creation of Star Wars?"

Comment: @K-H-W All good points, I edited my answer in response and removed or edited the references you pointed out.